# Definition of irrational surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ an irrational surface (complex algebraic projective variety of dimension 2 over the field of complex number)
I know the definition of rational surface and the relations between ruled surfaces. is it correct to say that an irrational surface is a non rational surface?
And i this case there are example of surfaces that are ruled and not rational?

Comment: Yes, "irrational" means exactly "not rational". Any ruled surface with base a curve of genus $>0$ is not rational.

Comment: on bouville i have found this: an irrational surface with $K_S^{2}>0$ is not ruled. Following your definition an irrational surface can be ruled.

Comment: There is no contradiction: you wrote _an irrational surface with (extra condition) is not ruled_. If you remove (extra condition), the statement is no longer true, but that's to be expected.